# How to see the Auto Reference section on Plugin Inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the latest Unity manual

https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/PluginInspector.html

they assert that the Plugin Inspector

now features an "Auto Reference" concept:

[image]

So using the latest Unity (and even trying .2 etc),

However no matter what I do I cannot make this appear. Every single Unity project I have tried, even Unity examples, does not have the feature.

How it looks for me ..

[image]

What is going on?

how to access the Auto Reference ?

Comment: Not to be a smart*** but are you updated to 2018.3 or newer?

Comment: precisely, 2018.3 - also tried .2 and some earlier ones.  Good question.

Comment: Just checked on 2018.3 for windows- same result. Auto reference not showing up. Tested it with an empty test.cpp file though, not sure if it needs anything referencable in there to work. But I'm assuming your libButtonPlugin contains actual code? Will check on 2019 tomorrow to see if it shows up there.

Comment: In 2019 Beta version it can be seen :)

Comment: @Aybe I actually tried that and it didn't show up!  :/  Maybe I made a mistake - will try again ...

Comment: See by yourself : https://ibb.co/zRTXcjv on 2019.1.0a13, note that it's only for managed plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr- "Auto reference" only works for managed plugins. that is a .dll file that was written in, and compiled from C#. Unmanaged plugins (dll's written in a language that is not C#, are unmanaged and can't be auto referenced)

edit: I just noticed there were more hidden comments, one of which was Aybe mentioning it working for managed DLL's.

edit2: if you want the project to test it out i can upload it.

---

I wanted to check if there was a difference between managed and unmanaged DLL's when inspecting in the editor (testing in Unity 2019, but I assume the same goes for 2018).

I made the following two DLL's. One in C# (managed) and one in CPP (unmanaged). I added some simply functionality to it to make sure it wouldn't be caused by having an empty dll.

**Managed C# plugin**

```
using System;

namespace TestDLLManaged
{
    public class TestDLLManaged
    {
        public static float Multiply(int a, float b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled it into a DLL targeting .Net 3.5 framework (unity 2018 and later versions support 4.x, but wanted to play it on the safe side) and placed the .dll file in the /Assets/ folder (Apparantly the Assets/Plugin folder is intended to be used with *native/unmanaged* plugins, and not managed).

**Unmanaged/native C++ plugin**

```
//header filer
#pragma once
#define TESTDLLMULTIPLY_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C"
{
    TESTDLLMULTIPLY_API float MultiplyNumbers(int a, float b);
}

//body
#include "TestDLLMultiply.h"

extern "C"
{
    float MultiplyNumbers(int a, float b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Also compiled this into a dll, and placed it in the /Assets/Plugin folder.

I call both DLL's inside `DLLImportTest.cs` and perform a simple calculation to make sure both DLL's are actually imported, and functioning like so

```
using static TestDLLManaged.TestDLLManaged;

public class DLLImportTest : MonoBehaviour
{  
    const float pi = 3.1415926535f;

    [DllImport("TestDLL", EntryPoint = "MultiplyNumbers")]
    public static extern float UnmanagedMultiply(int a, float b);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("validating unmanaged, expeceted result = 100: {0}", UnmanagedMultiply(10, 10f));
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("validating managed, expeceted result = 100:  {0}", Multiply(10, 10f));
    }
}
```

When inspecting the DLL's in the editor it seems that the Managed (C#) plugin **does** have the option to `auto reference` and the Unmanaged/native (cpp) dll indeed **doens't** have the functionality. Now I don't actually know *why* this is the case, as it is nowhere to be found in the documentation. Maybe it's a bug, maybe there is another reason behind it. I may make a forum post about it later asking for more clarification.

---

As a little extra I decided to run a benchmark the two function, and to my surprise found that the managed C# plugin was actually *faster* than the cpp one.

```
 private void BenchMark()
{
    Stopwatch watch1 = new Stopwatch();
    watch1.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        UnmanagedMultiply(1574, pi);
    }
    watch1.Stop();
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Unmanaged multiply took {0} milliseconds", watch1.Elapsed);

    Stopwatch watch2 = new Stopwatch();
    watch2.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        Multiply(1574, pi);
    }
    watch2.Stop();
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("Managed multiply took {0} milliseconds", watch2.Elapsed);
}
```

Results:

`Unmanaged multiply took 00:00:00.1078501 milliseconds`

`Managed multiply took 00:00:00.0848208 milliseconds`

---

For anyone wishing to view the differences/experiment with it themselves, i've made a git-hub repo [here](http://%20github.com/RemyRM/Unity_AutoReference_test/tree/master) containing the project i used above.

Comment: thanks for this.  in the first instance, I just plain did not notice it only works on the new beta '19 ........

Comment: That's weird. According to the documentation it should work in 2018.3 aswel  https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/PluginInspector.html . I'll take a look at it tomorrow. If not the docs are incorrect

Comment: @Fattie I just tried my test project in '18.3. And I *am* seeing the "auto reference" option on managed plugins. this is done on windows version though (I think you are running on mac?) https://gyazo.com/ac83874f4b137bbaebc12952778527a3

Comment: I've uploaded the project here https://github.com/RemyRM/Unity_AutoReference_test/tree/master Maybe you can validate wether or not it works for mac

Comment: Ahh !  You're totally resolved it, @remy_rm .  In fact this feature is only for dlls ("managed plugins" as Unity calls them). - you cracked it !

Comment: bountyized this great answer !  :)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been nicely resolved by @remy_rm

## Compiled c# dlls ("managed plugins") do have the auto-reference feature

[image]

## Actual native plugins ("unmanaged plugins") do *NOT* have the auto-reference feature

[image]

In fact this does apply identically on both PC and Mac:

[image]

Unity (sometimes) refers to:

- c# compiled as a dll as "managed plugins"; and they (sometimes) refer to
- native plugins (say, an actual static library for iPhone which is compiled C) as "unmanaged plugins".

(Whereas, all other Unity-related writing on the www generally refers to compiled c# as "dlls" and native plugins as "plugins".)

The auto-reference system is only for compiled c# .. "managed plugins".

A huge thanks to @remy_rm for spending hours resolving this issue.

Unity are trying and trying to improve their comic documentation - not quite there yet  :)

Comment: A small correction to "The auto-reference system is only for compiled dlls." should be " The auto reference system is only for *managed* dll's. as a dll is always a compiled piece of code, and what dictates if it is a managed or unmanaged (unmanaged also called native) dll is dictated by the original language of the dll. "plugin" is just an ambigious name that can refer to *any* source of code outside of unity scripts, and a dll is just *one* way of making plugins. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186413/discussion-between-remy-rm-and-fattie (SO prompted me to create a chat for this topic)

Comment: yes, you're right ... it's hard to phrase that the right way!  :)

Comment: yeah it is quite a mess, and the fact that unity's documentation isn't clear doens't help at all either!